# Threads hang when flask application is opened in several devices/tabs/browsers

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, flask

I'm in the middle of a project that uses peer-to-peer and server-client architecture. I have a server that communicates with another device through sockets (I have three sockets for both server and device). Each socket is responsible for a certain type of information. I also need the tasks associated with each socket to work in parallel.

Let me explain further: I have a device (GPU) that is processing images. This GPU will need to send to server three different things in parallel. So I'm using three threads and three sockets. On the server side I have three threads("listeners") that will need to connect to the three GPU "clients". After there are three connections, three more threads are open one for each socket and task. Basically the gpu tries to connect to the server (3 sockets) and when the connections are made, each listener creates another thread for the task. When I open the Flask application everything works fine, the info is driven from server to browser without problems. But when I open the app on another tab or browser or computer, the server part hangs. At this point only one task is working on server side.
I would like to give you some code, but this is company property so I can't.

I'll give you a pseudo-code.

```
if __name__=="__main__"
    threading.Thread(target=app.listen1).start()
    app.run(threaded)

def listen1():
     with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s1, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s2, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s3:
       s1.bind((HOST, PORT))
       s1.listen()
       s2.bind((HOST, PORT2))
       s2.listen()
       s3.bind((HOST, PORT3))
       s3.listen()
       while True:
          conn1, addr1 = s1.accept()
          conn2, addr2 = s2.accept()
          conn3, addr3 = s3.accept()
          ident = json.loads(conn1.recv(1024))
          if db.existStream(ident['id'])==True:
             conn1.send(b'True')
             threading.Thread(target=client1, args=(conn1, addr1)).start()
             conn2.send(b'True')
             threading.Thread(target=client2, args=(conn2, addr2)).start()
             conn3.send(b'True')
             threading.Thread(target=client3, args=(conn3, addr3)).start()   
          else:
             conn1.send(b'False')
             conn2.send(b'False')
             conn3.send(b'False')
          
def client1(conn, addr):
     buffer1=b''
     while True:
        length= int.from_bytes(conn.recv(1024), 'big')
        if length==0:
           break;
        conn.send(b"ACK")
        while len(buffer1)<length:        
            data = conn.recv(262144)
            buffer1 += data
        buffer2=json.loads(buffer1.decode('utf-8'))
        overlay(buffer2['frame'], buffer2['sectorX'])
        if 'confidence' in buffer2:
           db.guardaFrame(buffer2['frame'], buffer2['sectorX'], buffer2['sectorY'], buffer2['timestamp'], buffer2['azimuth'], buffer2['elevation'])  
           db.guardaAlerta(buffer2['frame'], buffer2['sectorX'], buffer2['sectorY'], buffer2['timestamp'], buffer2['azimuth'], buffer2['elevation'], buffer2['confidence'])
        else:
           db.guardaFrame(buffer2['frame'], buffer2['sectorX'], buffer2['sectorY'], buffer2['timestamp'], buffer2['azimuth'], buffer2['elevation'])  
        buffer1=b''
          
def client2(conn, addr):
     buffer1=b''
     while True:
        length= int.from_bytes(conn.recv(1024), 'big')
        if length==0:
           break;
        conn.send(b"ACK")
        while len(buffer1)<length:        
            data = conn.recv(262144)
            buffer1 += data
            
        global Frame
        Frame= b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + buffer1 + b'\r\n'
        buffer1=b''
          
def client3(conn, addr):
     buffer1=b''
     while True:
        length= int.from_bytes(conn.recv(1024), 'big')
        if length==0:
           break;
        conn.send(b"ACK")
        while len(buffer1)<length:        
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            buffer1 += data
            
        buffer2=json.loads(buffer1.decode('utf-8'))
        global azimuth
        azimuth=buffer2['azimuth']
```

So, in conclusion, everything works fine when the user only opens a browser window. When the user opens on another computer (of the same network), on in another tab, the clients hang and don't do their tasks (except one). I hope this is enough for you to understand.

Thanks

EDIT: Forgot to mention, the code should be able to accept more equal devices. I mean I need to "listen" for more connections.

EDIT2: So I decided to show the code for better understanding. The "If ..." is on another file.

Comment: Your code is very redundant, for instance you only need one `listen` function and just send in the HOST and PORT number.  As for the clients, I am not sure where you are running those?

Comment: You are correct, the code is redundant. When I implemented the code I wanted to have 3 pairs of listeners and clients. Just for intuition. I just changed the code for 1 listener and the code works. By the way, yesterday I tried to run the app on three different devices and the app didn't crash, except when it was opened in Mozilla. On google Chrome everything works has expected. Is there a reason for firefox to crash the app?

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your threading in a class is a bad idea, since the instantiation of the class will force it to be single threaded.

```
class Server:
  def __init__(self, port):
      self.port = port

  def client(self):
      task

  def listen(self):
      socket created
      while true:
         do stuff
         break
     return

if __name__=="__main__"
     ports = [123,124,125]
     threads = [for p in ports in threading.Thread(Server(p).listen)]
     threads.join()
```

Here is a non functioning example of how gevent works to make this async:

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey, spawn
monkey.patch_all()

def listener(HOST, PORT, client):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen()
        while True:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            ident = json.loads(conn.recv(1024))
            if db.existStream(ident['id']) == True:
                conn.send(b'True')
                spawn(client,conn, addr)
            else:
                conn.send(b'False')

def client1(conn, addr):
    buffer1 = b''
    while True:
        length = int.from_bytes(conn.recv(1024), 'big')
        if length == 0:
            break;
        conn.send(b"ACK")
        while len(buffer1) < length:
            data = conn.recv(262144)
            buffer1 += data
        buffer2 = json.loads(buffer1.decode('utf-8'))
        overlay(buffer2['frame'], buffer2['sectorX'])
        if 'confidence' in buffer2:
            db.guardaFrame(buffer2['frame'], buffer2['sectorX'], buffer2['sectorY'], buffer2['timestamp'],
                           buffer2['azimuth'], buffer2['elevation'])
            db.guardaAlerta(buffer2['frame'], buffer2['sectorX'], buffer2['sectorY'], buffer2['timestamp'],
                            buffer2['azimuth'], buffer2['elevation'], buffer2['confidence'])
        else:
            db.guardaFrame(buffer2['frame'], buffer2['sectorX'], buffer2['sectorY'], buffer2['timestamp'],
                           buffer2['azimuth'], buffer2['elevation'])
        buffer1 = b''


def client2(conn, addr):
    buffer1 = b''
    while True:
        length = int.from_bytes(conn.recv(1024), 'big')
        if length == 0:
            break;
        conn.send(b"ACK")
        while len(buffer1) < length:
            data = conn.recv(262144)
            buffer1 += data

        global Frame
        Frame = b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + buffer1 + b'\r\n'
        buffer1 = b''


def client3(conn, addr):
    buffer1 = b''
    while True:
        length = int.from_bytes(conn.recv(1024), 'big')
        if length == 0:
            break;
        conn.send(b"ACK")
        while len(buffer1) < length:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            buffer1 += data

        buffer2 = json.loads(buffer1.decode('utf-8'))
        global azimuth
        azimuth = buffer2['azimuth']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hosts = (('host1','80',client1),('host2','80',client2),('host3','80',client3))
    threads = [spawn(listener, h,p,c) for h,p,c in hosts]
    gevent.joinall(threads)
```

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for your answer. What about the "listen" function to create another thread for the client function? Can I do: `  def listen(self):
      socket created
      while true:
         do stuff
         threading.Thread(client)
     return `

Comment: Also the 'client's are different from each other. Using the code above would create the same client for each listener thread.

Comment: Not sure you need to create a new thread, couldn't you just call the client function in the same thread? 
Honestly this is WAAAY easier with gevent

Comment: My client functions have while loops to keep getting info from device (GPU). Lets just say in the case you mentioned I call the client function. Will the listener thread continue its flow? By logic I think the listener thread will be stuck on the client function. Am I right? Thanks

Comment: Well then you would just startup three listeners, and three clients in 6 threads.  However I need actual code to see what you are using, and what libraries you are using.

Comment: Hi, I just updated the code. Regards

Comment: I am still confused why you are creating the same function in `listen` over and over again when one function would suffice.

Comment: I changed the code. But my real issue (apparently) is that when I open the firefox or edge, the threads stop processing. Lets just say I have 2 Chrome browser opened in two different computers. Everything works fine as both computers receive information from the server. But if there is a third computer that opens firefox or edge browser, the server stops on the three computers. I know this because one of the threads send a stream of frames to the browser. When firefox is opened the streams on the chrome computers stop.

Comment: use an async library like gevent instead.  monkey patch all and it makes it easy.

Comment: After some debugging, I noticed that the problem is in this line of code `length= int.from_bytes(conn.recv(1024), 'big')`. The thread client2 gets stuck in this line when two or more tabs are open of the same page. The thing is the code should be independent from how many tabs get open on a session. This only happens in this thread. The other two threads can work in several tabs.